# How to Select All and Copy in Nano or Vi

Tags: linux, shell, unix, vi, nano

I want to select all (960 lines) of my script file that is in UNIX and paste it to text file on windows.
I have tried gg"+yG, gg#+yG, :%y and many other things but those only yank and don't paste to my text file on windows.
I have been copying file to a windows machine,open file in local editor and then copy/paste. Wondering if there is a better and easier way of doing it.

Comment: How are these UNIX and Windows computers connected to each other? And surely you're not using vi and nano at the same time.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen no not at the same time. UNIX box is where I work, but the computer has windows OS.

Comment: @James: That makes no sense. How are these two computers connected to each other? Are you accessing the UNIX machine over SSH? Is it a virtual machine?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen That's right. over SSH.

Comment: Can you `scp` the file? Do you connect to the Unix box from Windows? Which program do you use to make the connection (that program can have a capture option).
Or could you just use `cat file` and copy-paste with the mouse.

Comment: @James: Do the best you can; for instance, mentioning _in the question_ that SSH is involved  is  a step in the right direction.

Comment: Copy the file to a windows machine, open in local editor and then copy/paste. Your remote unix machine knows nothing about your local machine clipboard.

Comment: @nsilent22 that's what I have been doing, but thought there might be a better way.

Comment: What terminal are using? Sometimes selecting everything with the mouse and then using windows clipboard works. If you are using ssh inside Microsoft cmd you can use the Window-Menu (left corner of the window) there is mark and copy command available but that copies the newline, so that is a real pain to use for multiple lines.

Comment: @WalterA I can scp the file from one server to another. And right I connect to Unix box from windows as I have stated above. Plus I use Putty to make connection. I hope it answers.

Comment: @LarsFischer I use Putty to connect to my servers and files in UNIX box. Selecting with the mouse is not an option here since I have too many lines.

Comment: See: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.1.1 Mouse Copy&Paste could be possible in putty

Comment: What is this question doing on StackOverflow to begin with? SO's scope is programming, and tools exclusively used for programming; text editors and clipboards are useful for all manner of things.

Answer (score 4):

SSH does not synchronize the system clipboards of the two systems - in fact there is no such thing as a "system clipboard" in a console session on most Unixen I know of. Text editors implement their own cut buffers and other software do not know about the contents.

If you need to transfer a file, I suggest using `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

Use scp or use the putty option Session > logging.